# grails application throws below exception server used tomcat8

Tags: tomcat8

Caused by: org.grails.core.exceptions.GrailsRuntimeException: org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.grails.core.exceptions.GrailsRuntimeException: org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.grails.core.exceptions.GrailsRuntimeException: org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.grails.core.exceptions.GrailsRuntimeException: org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.grails.core.exceptions.GrailsRuntimeException: org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.grails.core.exceptions.GrailsRuntimeException: org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.grails.core.exceptions.GrailsRuntimeException: org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.grails.core.exceptions.GrailsRuntimeException: org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.grails.core.exceptions.GrailsRuntimeException: org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.grails.core.exceptions.GrailsRuntimeException: org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.grails.core.exceptions.GrailsRuntimeException: org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.grails.core.exceptions.GrailsRuntimeException: org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.grails.core.exceptions.GrailsRuntimeException: org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.grails.core.exceptions.GrailsRuntimeException: org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.grails.core.exceptions.GrailsRuntimeException: org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.grails.core.exceptions.GrailsRuntimeException: org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.grails.core.exceptions.GrailsRuntimeException: org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.grails.core.exceptions.GrailsRuntimeException: org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.grails.core.exceptions.GrailsRuntimeException: org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.grails.core.exceptions.GrailsRuntimeException: org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.grails.core.exceptions.GrailsRuntimeException: org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.grails.core.exceptions.GrailsRuntimeException: org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.grails.core.exceptions.GrailsRuntimeException: org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.grails.core.exceptions.GrailsRuntimeException: org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.grails.core.exceptions.GrailsRuntimeException: org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.grails.core.exceptions.GrailsRuntimeException: org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.grails.core.exceptions.GrailsRuntimeException: org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.grails.core.exceptions.GrailsRuntimeException: org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.grails.core.exceptions.GrailsRuntimeException: org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.grails.core.exceptions.GrailsRuntimeException: org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.grails.core.exceptions.GrailsRuntimeException: org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.grails.core.exceptions.GrailsRuntimeException: org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.grails.core.exceptions.GrailsRuntimeException: org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.grails.core.exceptions.GrailsRuntimeException: org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Handler processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.StackOverflowError
at org.grails.web.errors.GrailsExceptionResolver.resolveViewOrForward(GrailsExceptionResolver.java:208)
at org.grails.web.errors.GrailsExceptionResolver.resolveException(GrailsExceptionResolver.java:93)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processHandlerException(DispatcherServlet.java:1222)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1034)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:984)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:901)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:635)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.grails.web.servlet.mvc.GrailsWebRequestFilter.doFilterInternal(GrailsWebRequestFilter.java:77)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101)
at org.springframework.boot.web.support.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:123)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:728)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:470)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:395)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:316)
at org.grails.web.mapping.UrlMappingUtils.forwardRequestForUrlMappingInfo(UrlMappingUtils.java:242)
at org.grails.web.errors.GrailsExceptionResolver.forwardRequest(GrailsExceptionResolver.java:215)
at org.grails.web.errors.GrailsExceptionResolver.resolveViewOrForward(GrailsExceptionResolver.java:199)
at org.grails.web.errors.GrailsExceptionResolver.resolveException(GrailsExceptionResolver.java:93)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processHandlerException(DispatcherServlet.java:1222)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1034)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:984)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:901)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:635)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.grails.web.servlet.mvc.GrailsWebRequestFilter.doFilterInternal(GrailsWebRequestFilter.java:77)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101)
at org.springframework.boot.web.support.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:123)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:728)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:470)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:395)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:316)
at org.grails.web.mapping.UrlMappingUtils.forwardRequestForUrlMappingInfo(UrlMappingUtils.java:242)
at org.grails.web.errors.GrailsExceptionResolver.forwardRequest(GrailsExceptionResolver.java:215)
at org.grails.web.errors.GrailsExceptionResolver.resolveViewOrForward(GrailsExceptionResolver.java:199)
at org.grails.web.errors.GrailsExceptionResolver.resolveException(GrailsExceptionResolver.java:93)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processHandlerException(DispatcherServlet.java:1222)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1034)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:984)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:901)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:635)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.grails.web.servlet.mvc.GrailsWebRequestFilter.doFilterInternal(GrailsWebRequestFilter.java:77)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101)
at org.springframework.boot.web.support.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:123)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:728)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:470)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:395)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:316)
at org.grails.web.mapping.UrlMappingUtils.forwardRequestForUrlMappingInfo(UrlMappingUtils.java:242)
at org.grails.web.errors.GrailsExceptionResolver.forwardRequest(GrailsExceptionResolver.java:215)
at org.grails.web.errors.GrailsExceptionResolver.resolveViewOrForward(GrailsExceptionResolver.java:199)
at org.grails.web.errors.GrailsExceptionResolver.resolveException(GrailsExceptionResolver.java:93)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processHandlerException(DispatcherServlet.java:1222)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1034)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:984)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:901)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:635)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.grails.web.servlet.mvc.GrailsWebRequestFilter.doFilterInternal(GrailsWebRequestFilter.java:77)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101)
at org.springframework.boot.web.support.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:123)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:728)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:470)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:395)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:316)
at org.grails.web.mapping.UrlMappingUtils.forwardRequestForUrlMappingInfo(UrlMappingUtils.java:242)
at org.grails.web.errors.GrailsExceptionResolver.forwardRequest(GrailsExceptionResolver.java:215)
at org.grails.web.errors.GrailsExceptionResolver.resolveViewOrForward(GrailsExceptionResolver.java:199)
at org.grails.web.errors.GrailsExceptionResolver.resolveException(GrailsExceptionResolver.java:93)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processHandlerException(DispatcherServlet.java:1222)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1034)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:984)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:901)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:635)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.grails.web.servlet.mvc.GrailsWebRequestFilter.doFilterInternal(GrailsWebRequestFilter.java:77)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101)

Comment: Add some details to your post. What you have done? What is not working?